# Java an unremoveable white space string

Tags: java, string, whitespace, equals

I have this string from mysql DB: it should be this: 2100428169/2010

this is my code

```
String str = rs.getString("str");
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+","");
str = str.trim();

char[] strCH = str.toCharArray();
```

and I get this:

```
[, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4, 2, 8, 1, 6, 9, /, 2, 0, 1, 0]
```

Why?

It's a problem because I need to use str1.equals(str) but it doesn't work because after

```
Object obj = (object)str;
```

It is in obj again with a space at the beginning like when I use `toCharArray` so it means `equals` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you tell us what is your result of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.chars().toArray()));`?

Comment: method chars is undefined for the type string... but I did this: System.out.println((int) hovno[0]); and it returns 65279

Comment: What do you get if you just do `System.out.println("\"" + str + "\"");`

Comment: The `trim` should remove any leading or trailing whitespace, regardless of the `replaceAll` regular expression. Please post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found solution:

it was problem because of ASCII 65279 is something from BOM and trim() doesn't work for it.

this helped: `str = str.replace("\uFEFF", "");`

Comment: You can also call `str = str.replaceAll("[\uFEFF\\s]+", "");` (no trim needed).

Comment: Replacing the character is good, but I would worry about how it got there in the first place.  Maybe it shouldn't be there, and there is a bug upstream you need to look at as well.

Answer (score 0):

Neither replaceAll() nor trim() will work for some characters.
Actually there are several characters that could not be removed with this method. I even saw some files having characters that could not be recognized by java compiler, which creates unbelievable situations.
trim() method removes all `\s` from ends of string and by replaceAll() you are removing all `\s` from your string.
Instead use following

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\w\\\\]+", "");
```

You don't need to call trim() now.