# Is there a way to remove leading whitespace of the first item in a CSV file?

Tags: java, string, csv

I've tried multiple methods to see if they would remove the leading whitespace of the first entry in my CSV file, but none of them seemed to work and I've also confirmed that I didn't accidentally type a space in my file.

I used String.replaceAll(" ", ""), String.trim(), String.strip(), but none of them worked.

```
for(int r = 0; r < 303; r++){
            String s = file.nextLine();
            s = s.replaceAll(" ", ""); //attempt to remove whitespace
            str_arr = s.split(",");

            for(int c = 0; c < 6; c++){
                str_arr[c] = str_arr[c].strip(); //2nd attempt
                System.out.println(str_arr[c]); //here it just prints the 
                                                  number 64 with a space in 
                                                  front of it
                data_set[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(str_arr[c]); 
            }
        }
```

All the strings do have their whitespace removed, it's just the very first entry number that still has a leading whitespace and that's causing the line Integer.parseInt(str_arr[c]) to return a NumberFormatException (I know this returns BECAUSE there's a leading whitespace).

Comment: _"I know this returns BECAUSE there's a leading whitespace"_ -- have you done a hex dump and verified that the "leading whitespace" is `0x20`?  It is most likely NOT whitespace but something like a Unicode BOM or maybe a non-breaking space (U+00A0). This is supported by the fact that _"I used String.replaceAll(" ", ""), String.trim(), String.strip(), but none of them worked."_

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm not sure what you mean by that because tbh I'm just an amateur programmer and all this complicated things do not make sense to me. How do I do a hex dump then?

Comment: Can you share a piece of csv?

Comment: @Jaja How can I do that, I don't seem to be able to attach a file.

Comment: @Phillip, for example: put it in cloud and share a link

Comment: @Bob what does `System.out.println((int)  s.charAt(0))` print?

Comment: @Jaja There you go https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wWDWVTGR422hU9o0E0l3Cagh4-mydhct/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JBNizet it prints out 65729, and I searched it up to be a zero-width no-break space

Comment: You have your answer then. it's not a white space. That's why replacing all the white spaces doesn't change anything to the string. You can just use `s = s.substring(1)` to remove the first character of a string, whatever that first character is.

Comment: @JBNizet then what can I do to remove this zero-width no-break space?

Comment: Read my edited comment.

Comment: Try this: `s = s.replaceAll("[\uFEFF\\s]+", "");`. Removes all whitespaces and any BOM's. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038672/java-an-unremoveable-white-space-string)

Comment: @Phillip the problem is fixed (may be), s. answer bellow, it was "\uFEFF" if you meet other problem check something like encoding e.g utf-8 ...

Answer (score -1):

You file is BOM, therefore we need other way to handle it, Please see 
[here](https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html) for more info.

```
public static void readCSV(){
    String p1 = "file ...\\heart.csv";

    List<String> linesInFile1 = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        linesInFile1 = Files.readAllLines(new File(p1).toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset() );
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StackOverflows.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    //69,1,145,233,150,1
    for(String ss:linesInFile1){
        for(String s: ss.split(",")){
            System.out.print(Integer.valueOf(removeUTF8BOM(s))+"   ");
        }   
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static String removeUTF8BOM(String s) {
    final String UTF8_BOM = "\uFEFF";
    if (s.startsWith(UTF8_BOM)) {
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Why downgraded this answer? Please give a comment

Answer (score -2):

You can use trim() method to remove whitespace.

```
String removeWhiteSpace = " Hello";
System.out.println(removeWhiteSpace.trim());
```

Comment: It is already established that trim does **not** work for the character that **appears** to look like a whitespace.

Comment: Then try to add trim() or strip() in your below mentioned line:
 data_set[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(str_arr[c].strip());

Comment: In **this particular case** that line would create an exception. Please read the post and the comments below it.